# SQL Left Join does not return all results

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two tables that I'm trying to join for customers that are going through a process. All customers get to step one, but only some progress to step two (table 2). 
Customers may start this process more than once at different times, and may get to step two in none, one, or many months. I'd like to know how many make this progression. 
Tables as an example:

Table_1

```
Cust1    1-Jan    
Cust2    10-Jan
Cust3    15-Jan
Cust1    2-Feb
```

Table_2

```
Cust1    5-Jan
Cust2    16-jan
```

My query to return results is:

```
SELECT t1.Cust, t1.Date1, t2.Date2
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 ON t1.Cust = t2.Cust
WHERE t2.Date is missing OR (t2.Date - t1.Date > 0 AND t2.Date - t1.Date < 10);
```

This returns:

```
Cust1  1-Jan    5-Jan
Cust2  10-Jan   16-Jan
Cust3  15-Jan
```

When what I want the query to return is:

```
Cust1  1-Jan    5-Jan
Cust1  2-Feb
Cust2  10-Jan   16-Jan
Cust3  15-Jan
```

The query seems to join Cust1 with 2-Feb and 5-Jan and then eliminates this because it doesn't match the filter. But I need the filter because Cust1 comes back in March. How do I keep this Feb entry in the final output? Help!

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: you should place where condition into join: `LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 ON t1.Cust = t2.Cust and (t2.Date is missing OR (t2.Date - t1.Date > 0 AND t2.Date - t1.Date < 10))`

Comment: What is your date column datatype

Comment: Date column is just a date column, simplified here for practicality. DBMS is actually Proc SQL in SAS EG, but should be the same for any SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `where` condition into your `on` clause:

```
SELECT t1.Cust, t1.Date1, t2.Date2
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 ON t1.Cust = t2.Cust 
                    AND t2.Date - t1.Date > 0 
                    AND t2.Date - t1.Date < 10
```

Comment: Thanks - this is almost there. I need the OR for those customers that don't repeat i.e. t2.Date2 is missing. If you change I can accept.

Comment: Well, the `left join` takes care of that: It makes sure that all records of the first table are listed, even if the `on` condition cannot be met and the fields of the second table will remain empty (=`null`).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose, that customers can start a process once a month (at least that what I observed), so it could be joined lie this:

```
SELECT t1.Cust, t1.Date1, t2.Date2
FROM Table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 ON (t1.Cust = t2.Cust AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, t1.Date1, t2.Date2) = 0)
```

Generally, you can use `DATEDIFF` to specify more narrow period, i.e. if you would like this difference to be less than 10 days you could use:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.Date1, t2.Date2) <= 10
```

Comment: It looks like the DBMS does matter for this - Proc SQL function is either DATDIF or INTCK. Also needs condition where Date2 is missing. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> The query seems to join Cust1 with 2-Feb and 5-Jan and then eliminates this because it doesn't match the filter.

Right!! This is because, whenever you use LEFT JOINed Table in WHERE clause then this will change the behaviour of LEFT JOIN and Act as INNER JOIN and As you know the INNER JOIN return only matching records.

To get work around to this problem Use WHERE Clause conditions IN Joining logic