# Get full drilldown of a sparce fact table

Tags: sql, olap, cube, dimensional-modeling, datamart

I have a transaction fact table and product,time and location as a dimension tables. This fact table is sparse so if no Pizzas sold in January there is no record for Pizza in fact table.

When I drill down by product aggregated results for Pizza which is not in the result. But I want it with 0 values as units_sold = 0.

A solution is to join product table to fact table with a left outer join. Then I can get the desired result.

---

- But when I cut with another dimension such as location or time, again those products are missing in the result.
- Outer join provides empty column for other dimensional foreign keys so WHERE clause will remove them again.

  ---

### How can I solve the problem? (I use ROLAP)

Use join condition is a good idea as some people answered. But I need more general solution.

For example,

### Table1

```
 person      birth year       death year

 a          1950               2006
 b          1952               2008
 c          1960               2007
 d          1953               1990
```

I want to get year by year count of the people that born between 1950-1953 and died in 2006-2008.

Like

```
birth = 1950   death = 2006   count = 1
birth = 1951   death = 2006   count = 0
...
```

Can we handle this scenario by using join conditions and where conditions appropriately.

Comment: Move the `WHERE` conditions into the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Left Join does not return all results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067701/sql-left-join-does-not-return-all-results)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks @Nick this will work. However still I like to know is there some general solution that can be implemented in OLAP cubes.

Comment: For example when we have two dimensions and we are perform a range cut and drilldown in each dimension. How can we obtain all the results corresponding to the every drilldown cell in the cube when the fact table is sparce.

Answer (score 0):

You want `LEFT JOIN`, and then `LEFT JOIN` again.  Then conditions go in the *`on`* clause.  Something like this:

```
select . . .
from products p left join
     fact f
     on p.product_id = f.product_id left join
     timedim td
     on f.time_id = td.time_id and
        td.month = 'January'
```

Comment: Using join condition instead of where condition is a good idea. However I still find a better solution.